# Unir valores de um array multidimensional

Tags: php

Gostaria de unir os valores dos resultados de um array
Exemplo:

```
<?php
$arrayName = array(
        array('ID' => 23456, 'nome' =>  'Beta', 'email' => 'zeca@sem.com'),
        array('ID' => 23456, 'nome' =>  'Beta', 'telefone' => '963526323'),
        array('ID' => 23455, 'nome' =>  'Joa', 'nem' => 'dio@sem.com'),
      );
      
print_r($arrayName)
?>
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23456
            [nome] => Beta
            [email] => zeca@sem.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23456
            [nome] => Beta
            [telefone] => 963526323
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23455
            [nome] => Joa
            [nem] => dio@sem.com
        )

)
```

Preciso fazer com que onde tenha ID iguais nas chaves ele una os valores divergentes,
resultado esperado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23456
            [nome] => Beta
            [email] => zeca@sem.com
            [telefone] => 963526323
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23455
            [nome] => Joa
            [nem] => dio@sem.com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você consegue isso criando um array associativo utilizando o `ID` como chave para conseguir identificar as mesmas correspondências e utilizando a função nativa `array_merge` para unificar as informações.

```php
<?php

$array = array(
    array('ID' => 23456, 'nome' =>  'Beta', 'email' => 'zeca@sem.com'),
    array('ID' => 23456, 'nome' =>  'Beta', 'telefone' => '963526323'),
    array('ID' => 23455, 'nome' =>  'Joa', 'nem' => 'dio@sem.com'),
);

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $result[$item['ID']] = array_merge($result[$item['ID']] ?? [], $item);
}

print_r($result);
```

O resultado:

```
Array
(
    [23456] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23456
            [nome] => Beta
            [email] => zeca@sem.com
            [telefone] => 963526323
        )

    [23455] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23455
            [nome] => Joa
            [nem] => dio@sem.com
        )

)
```

Se por acaso não queira os IDs ainda como chaves do array, pode fazer `$result = array_values($result)`